# c# TCP IP client and server no respond error

Tags: c#, tcp

i have a simple TCP/IP client and server that does not work:
i want to use it to transfer data between some clients and  a server
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QCfH.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49sLE.jpg)

on server side i have:

```
   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;

namespace TCP_IP_Server
{
    public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
        private ArrayList nSockets;
        public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IPHostEntry IPhost = Dns.GetHostByName(Dns.GetHostName());
            lblStatus.Text = "IP Address: " + IPhost.AddressList[0].ToString();
            nSockets = new ArrayList();
            Thread thdListner = new Thread(new ThreadStart(listnerThread));
        }

        public void listnerThread()
        {
            TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(8080);
            tcpListener.Start();
            while(true)
            {
                Socket handlerSocket = tcpListener.AcceptSocket();
                if(handlerSocket.Connected)
                {
                    Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
                    lbConnections.Items.Add(handlerSocket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString() + " Connected.");
                    lock (this)
                    {
                        nSockets.Add(handlerSocket);
                    }
                    ThreadStart thdstHandler = new ThreadStart(handlerThread);
                    Thread thdHnadler = new Thread(thdstHandler);
                    thdHnadler.Start();
                }
            }
        }

        public void handlerThread()
        {
            Socket handlerSocket = (Socket)nSockets[nSockets.Count - 1];
            NetworkStream networkStream = new NetworkStream(handlerSocket);
            int thisRead = 0;
            int BlockSize = 1024;
            byte[] dataByte = new byte[BlockSize];
            lock (this)
            {
                Stream fileStream = File.OpenWrite(@"%userprofile%\desktop\SubmitedFile.txt");
                while(true)
                {
                    thisRead = networkStream.Read(dataByte, 0, BlockSize);
                    fileStream.Write(dataByte, 0, thisRead);
                    if (thisRead == 0)
                        break;
                }
                fileStream.Close();
            }
            lbConnections.Items.Add("File Written.");
            handlerSocket = null;
        }
    }
}
```

and on Clinet side:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;

namespace TCP_IP_Client
{
    public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
        public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ofdBrowse.ShowDialog();
            txtFile.Text = ofdBrowse.FileName;
        }

        private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Stream fileStream = File.OpenRead(txtFile.Text);
            byte[] fileBuffer = new byte[fileStream.Length];
            fileStream.Read(fileBuffer, 0, (int)fileStream.Length);
            TcpClient tcp = new TcpClient(txtServer.Text, 8080);
            NetworkStream networkStream = tcp.GetStream();
            networkStream.Write(fileBuffer, 0, fileBuffer.GetLength(0));
            networkStream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

i am running the server on a VPS that hase statick IP adress and the client on my own pc, but after hiting send button an exception occures:

```
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond **.**.**.**:8080
```

Comment: Regarding that specific error, the TcpListener(portnum) constructor is obsolete, use one of the other ctors that accept an IP address or EndPoint &  make sure whatever is in txtServer.Text in the client matches.

Comment: @AlexK. i am sure that the address in txtServer.Text matches Server IP, i also changed that "TcpListener(portnum)" to "TcpListener(ServerIP,PortNumber)" but no success

Comment: Turn off your firewall(s) and try again. If that works - start them up again and open the port.

Comment: You need to start the Thread thdListner.start()

Comment: @fredrik i have added TCP Port 8080 to the server's firewall, and also disabled the firewall on my machine, but that did not work

Comment: @Oswald so... should i start it on form load?
i thaught i will start with this line "Thread thdListner = new Thread(new ThreadStart(listnerThread));" because a thread start is define while thread definition.

Comment: I'm not sure but he may won't be start with your line. You can easily check it if you put a breakpoint in the method "listnerThread"

Comment: @Oswald No it did not start, thank you, i have added "thdListner.Start();" to the load event handler, it now starts listnerThread but its still not working

Comment: I've putted an answer to mark as solution

Comment: Have you checked all the network things (firewall, ip, etc.)

Comment: @Oswald Yes, i disabled the firewall on my machine and added TCP port 8080 to VPS's firewall in inbound section

Comment: If you try to execute the client on the same machine as the server, does it work?

Comment: @Oswald yes it works!

Comment: Then it is not anymore a programmatic error. Now it's a networking problem.

Comment: so how can i figure out what is this networking problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Programmatic Issue**

Don't forget to start the thread after creating

```cs
private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IPHostEntry IPhost = Dns.GetHostByName(Dns.GetHostName());
    lblStatus.Text = "IP Address: " + IPhost.AddressList[0].ToString();
    nSockets = new ArrayList();
    Thread thdListner = new Thread(new ThreadStart(listnerThread));
    thdListner.start();
}
```

**2. Network Issue**

- Take the IP-address used by the code to host the server and Ping the address on the client.
- If succeeded, check the firewall settings of the server, client (may temporarly switch of the firewall to check if this is the problem)
- If you're using dns names execute an nslookup  on the client